# How can Captain America survive a skydive without a parachute?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

At the start of the recent [*Captain America: The Winter Soldier* trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLWsK1ZFunA), Cap jumps from a plane.  Except he does this without a parachute.  In *Avengers*, he does use a chute when jumping from a Quinjet to catch up to Thor, Iron Man, and Loki, which seemed to indicate he needs a parachute to land safely.

How can he survive a skydive without a parachute?

Comment: He's a superhero?

Comment: [He says parachutes are for girls](http://i.imgur.com/Sytuj9b.jpg) :P

Comment: It should be noted that *occasionally* skydivers will survive falls where their parachute fails to open, and that during WWII some airmen survived falling from bombers without them. This is rare, and a combination of factors is at play: updrafts, landing on slopes (even snow-covered at times), landing on mud or other things that can cushion the fall, and even how they chose to land (you can break your legs/hips, or your skull: pick one). So even normal humans do this once in awhile.

Comment: @JohnO: I choose finger.

Comment: @JohnO: wait damnit I’m a web developer, I make a living from my fingers. Toe. I choose toe.

Comment: Something to consider with those examples is that in Avengers he had just recently been revived and was probably relearning his limits.  By the time The Winter Soldier happens, he has had plenty of time to figure out what he's capable of so he doesn't need to be as cautious.

Comment: For what it's worth, humans in real life have survived falls from airplanes without parachutes, and that's without considering superhuman physique and a shield that absorbs all vibration perfectly to deaden the momentum of his fall.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**This scene is an homage to an obscure comic Tales of Suspense #75, in which Captain America is falling from a plane without a parachute.**

[image]

Captain America plummeting to his death after blowing up the Skullship. Where is his parachute? (Stan Lee later admits they forgot to draw it, but this was a famous event in that it increased interest in Marvel's No-Prize, an award for explaining events "in story" that would rationalize mistakes made in the production of the book.)

[image]

Given the Captain's perfect physiology, we are expected to believe he can somehow survive a fall into water without serious injury. And we did.

Comment: Also, Captain America is sometimes depicted using his shield to cushion a great fall. Because of the [vibranium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Vibranium) component that is part of his shield it can absorb kinetic energy to a certain extent. Probably not enough to survive a skydive, though.

Comment: Oh yes, I know this but I had trouble hunting through my collection for the picture of him using his shield AS A LANDING DEVICE when he fell off a building... I figured this was what they were homaging, upto and including the picturesque diving position...

Comment: Also turns out that vibranium ***floats*** I guess? \*FURIOUS FACEPALM\* OWWW

Comment: Even if vibranium doesn't float, [his shield only weighs 10-12 pounds](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34923/how-heavy-is-captain-americas-shield).

Comment: That depends on who you ask. An engineer in Wired estimated it weighed approximately 19.9 KG based on its interactions in the movie. It was compelling evidence, filled with lots of [numbers and exotic symbols.](http://www.wired.com/2014/03/whats-mass-captain-americas-shield/)

Comment: @Thaddeus Yes, but that article has a major unstated assumption--that the physics in superhero movies are the same as in the real world. I'm pretty sure that's not true.

Comment: I will agree with that. Comic universe physics are far stranger than anything we can recognize in our universe.

Answer (score 11):

The trailer shows him landing in water. In the movie *The Avengers* he parachutes over land. I guess the idea of hitting water at 200 miles an hour appeals to him more than hitting a mountainous forest.

Comment: This. The clip shows him (sky)diving into the water feet first. With him being a superhero, I assume this shouldn't pose a problem at all, maybe even for us regular humans.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6k0kkSHiiPE

Comment: From that height, it would cause a problem for regular humans. I’ve jumped into water from 40 feet, and because my posture was off, it hurt. From a plane, a regular human would be likely to die from the injuries, or at least injured enough to preclude swimming, and thus make drowning likely.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thankfully, the Capt. has [Super Hero Steroids](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruMO9SXto0Q&t=17s). ;-)

Comment: it depends on how high you go. If you are 200 feet above water and you land just right, you probably gonna break your legs, but live. I've done 90 feet and it tickled and shot water up the butt. no biggie

Answer (score 4):

Though the accepted answer says it is a reference to an old comic (and this is probably true), his survival is not entirely based on Superhero Steroids. In the scene you watch him fall, but just before impact he snaps into a pencil dive. This would allow him to hit with minimal force, and (yes) due in part to the indestructible factor given to him by the Super Soldier Serum he would survive the fall. See [This link](http://www.faa.gov/data_research/research/med_humanfacs/oamtechreports/1960s/media/AM65-12.pdf).

Comment: It's not actually a pencil dive position, it's referred to as the Cross and Cover, it's taught to Coast Guard Aviation Survival Technitions (think Ashton Kutcher in the Guardian).  A pencil dive would have his hands at his sides, but his arms are tucked in with his hands covering his face to prevent water from going up his nose.  It's a pretty plausible way to enter from such a height.

Comment: @Monty129 you know you could have just added that to the answer, thank you for the information