# Who is the heaviest superhero in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Including all technology, weapons, etc., which MCU superhero weighs the most (on Earth, just to simplify things)?

Is it:

- Iron Man, with his mechanical suit?
- The Hulk, with all of his muscle mass?
- Black Panther, with his vibranium suit?
  (A question about the weight of vibranium can be found in [How heavy is Captain America's shield?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34923/how-heavy-is-captain-americas-shield))
- Thor, with either his Uru hammer or

  > Stormbreaker

  along with the armor he's always wearing?
- Or is it someone else?

Do not count spaceships, huge turbolasers, etc.  Suits count, but not vehicles.

Comment: [**Ego**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ego) would be the heaviest _character_.

Comment: OK yes, but Ego isn't a superhero.

Comment: I would image Hulk and Iron Man in his Hulkbuster armor are pretty close together

Comment: Hmm, if you consider that The Hulk is always part of Banner, then Banner in the Hulkbuster would surely be some kind of contender here.

Comment: When I saw the title I thought it was asking about the fattest superhero

Comment: @Möoz The Hulk's mass is clearly not always part of Banner. To count that would be ridiculous.

Comment: Does MCU Hulk gain muscle mass indefinitely with anger, like in 616?

Comment: I think @Loki needs to step in here and confirm that Thor ain’t heavy, he’s his brother.

Comment: Per the comics, I believe the Hulk's standard weight was 1000 lbs. (a half a ton), at least in the 1970s and 1980s.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I literally read that in Austin Powers' accent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Purely based on speculation on size and "apparent" weight, I'd go with:

## 1. Huge Ant-Man a.k.a "Giant Man"

**[Ant-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant-Man)** has shown that he's capable of increasing his size, and apparent weight, he grows to some ridiculous proportions of > 70 ft tall, hitherto known as "Giant Man". It seems that his apparent weight changes and increases with him. I'd put him at at least the 100 tons range. A behemoth by any measure and a definite winner for our category.

## 2. Bulker-Buster

The [**Hulk/Bruce Banner**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hulk) duality in my eyes should be considered, *one*. Therefore, at all times, their weight should be technically combined. Now, based on The Hulk's size and bulk, I'd put him at the 200 kg mark, minimum. Couple that with Mark Ruffalo's approximate 1.73 m measurement, I'd put him at roughly 75 kg (similar build to myself). So, he's definitely around the 1–2 ton range when in the Hulkbuster suit.

### Others

The following will fit in a similar category and range:

- Tony Stark + Hulkbuster
- Tony Stark + any other suit
- War Machine
- etc.

## 3. Groot

"Why don't you make like a tree, and leaf?"

<sup>sorry</sup>

Our old tree friend, [**Groot**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Groot), is definitely large, and heavy. I'd put him in a naturally high level, since just walking around he looks and sounds like he's at least 200 kg. Coupled with the ability to extend himself and increase his size (and apparent weight), I'd say he has a huge potential to become one of the heaviest superheroes.

## 4. Peter Quill?

Ok, I'm gonna start stretching this, since for the most part, I don't think we'll get a more accurate answer<sup>*</sup>.

[**Peter Quill**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Star-Lord) is part Celestial, and has access to supposed Celestial powers, namely the white-glowy-power-thingy. Now, as evidenced by Ego in *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 2*, Ego was able to use this power to manipulate the very space and matter around him, to manifest himself as a moon-sized planet, fully-equipped with a shape-shifting body and interplanetary travel ship. Theoretically, and potentially, Quill has the ability to become endlessly big (and heavy). Coupled with his huge ego (lol, yes I did), he's definitely humongous.

<sup>why stop there?</sup>

Let's see how far we can stretch this thing<sup>@</sup>

## 5. Colossus<sup>#</sup>

As far as superheroes go, [**Colossus**](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Rasputin) is one mega-super-ukulele. Able to manipulate his body to become pure metal. Coupled with his massive size, this dude's definitely a contender for this title. Exactly how big and heavy? Well, I'd put him in the 0.5 to 1 ton range. (Based purely on my minimal ability to judge weights).

## 6. Beast-mode heroes

Look, I'll make a separate category for heroes that will probably be in a similar category that I'll call "The Beast Modes". These are characters that have a natural... bulkiness. Large enough to beat most humans in size-weight ratio, but not quite big enough to make a dent in the floor as they walk:

- Thor

  - Thor wearing, or holding anything
- Drax
- Cpt. Steve Rogers

  - Cpt. Steve Rogers holding, or wearing anything
- T'Challa

  - T'Challa wearing, or holding anything
- You get the point...

Let's put them at the 100–120 kg range.

---

***** Yes, I'm aware that some smart ass like my mate Valorum will probably come along any minute now and cite a junior novelisation or something, or KutuluMike will come along with screenshots of comic panels. But let's have fun while we can.

**@** That's what...

**#** Hey, you didn't say we couldn't stretch it to the Fox franchise, since Deadpool is somewhat in the middle, I'll happily include this.

Comment: Ant-Man technology is not about changing actual mass of thing but "shorten the distance between an object's molecules, effectively reducing its size while maintaining its mass" (from [wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ant-Man_Suit) )

Comment: “The Hulk/Bruce Banner duality in my eyes should be considered, one. Therefore, at all times, their weight should be technically combined.” I think a [$13 bathroom scale](https://www.amazon.com/Electronic-Bathroom-Tempered-Platform-Technology/dp/B01HCDUUKW/ref=sr_1_29_s_it?s=hpc&ie=UTF8&qid=1538644971&sr=1-29&keywords=bathroom+scale) could disprove your theory (as long as non-Hulk Banner steps on it first).

Comment: @Ckankonmange: 1. Wikias aren’t sources, they’re just the output of an unidentifiable bunch of authors. 2. Mass, sure, but Ant-Man’s *weight* clearly changes when he shrinks, otherwise he’d be far too heavy to ride on a flying ant. The sound effects in the airport fight scene in Civil War certainly suggest he gets heavier when he gets bigger too.

Comment: @pauld.waite I think the only think we can really say on the subject of Ant Man technology is that it’s super inconsistent and definitely follows the rule of cool rather than logic.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Is it a good enough source for you? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96339/96904
But I agree with Paul: MCU is not consistent with this power.

Comment: I think some of your numbers are way too low. Sumo wrestlers reach 200kg and the Hulk looks a lot bigger than them, plus he is mostly muscle.

Comment: # yes they did say no Fox, the question is explicitly MCU only

Comment: When does Groot demonstrate the ability to increase apparent weight? Other than regular organic growth from Baby Groot onwards, there's no indication of weight increase while making rapid temporary growths.

Comment: @Ckankonmange As an aside, this is why Giant-Man bothers me. The whole point of his relatively increased strength as Ant-Man is that his mass is compressed into a smaller volume. Surely then Giant-Man shouldn't be dense enough to pack the sort of punch he does, or even to wade through water....

Comment: @user - Agreed, I'm 150kg and I'm nowhere near Hulk's size. Gotta be 450+

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit watching a giant Paul Rudd try to run a body of water only to realize he's buoyant (boy-ant?) sure would make for some great cinema.

Comment: #2 or #3 should be Thanos. He WAS on Earth, after all. And Colossus doesn't count - he's not part of the MCU... yet.

Comment: -1 for all the stretching.

Comment: @Omegacron They said heroes only.

Comment: Someone could be a smartass (myself namely) and stretch it to include the Guardians when they held hands and held the Power Stone. Hmmm, thinking...

Comment: Maybe missed Wolverine and his adamantium skeleton?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat - Wolverine w/adamantium is approx. 300-350lbs. Besides... he's not in the MCU yet.

Comment: @T.J.L. That's what _she_ said :p

Answer (score 16):

Vision. He is able to change his mass at will as shown in Civil War when Scarlet Which forces him to gain mass until he sinks through the floor and when he headbutts antman at low speed to knock him over.

Ant man's ability supposedly works by changing the distance between atoms but that is not represented in the films consistently as his weight is anything from body weight to a feather to fit the choreography. When he is big he always acts as though he is massive. But even in his heaviest it is unlikely to be more than vision.

Thors hammer isn't heavy it is magically unable to be lifted by anything other than Thor. But either way, Vision can lift the hammer so I guess Vision holding the hammer wearing the ant man suit would be the correct answer.

Comment: She doesn't force him to gain mass, she just moves him into the floor while he is phasing.

Comment: @OrangeDog I assumed that she was forcing him to gain mass the same way she forced him to phase out to drop Hawkeye. Gaining mass is still one of visions powers.

Comment: changing density is one of Vision's powers (and is how he phases). It's not established whether it involves a change in mass as well.

Comment: @OrangeDog unless he loses volume proportionally it does.

Comment: Not when things like Pym particles exist.

Comment: @OrangeDog I don't really know what you mean, you mean he gets smaller, raises his density but the pimms particles increase the size between each atom? But if he appears the same size that would mean that he is only changing his density in regards to atomic interactions. Which would not give him the abilities he demonstrates.

Comment: I mean science pretty much goes out the window. For example he doesn't change volume, nor does his mass change, but his atoms all shrink so he can phase through stuff.

Comment: Just to up-vote this answer i created this account.

Comment: The are two good answers here!  Sorry, but I have to go with the other one.  I would choose both if I could!

Answer (score 6):

I'm originally thought the heaviest might well have been Tony Stark in the Mk. 2 suit -- that was the first iteration after he was back from Afghanistan, the one built in actual steel.  Heavy enough that it crashed through the (seemingly helipad or parking capable) roof of his underground garage when he landed it after the maiden flight -- just before replacing it with the seemingly lighter gold-titanium alloy Mk. 3.

It was pointed out, however (thanks, @OrangeDog), that Rhodes, as War Machine, originally wore the Mk. 2 suit with heavy machine guns or aircraft cannon and missiles added, so that version (War Machine 1.0, Mk. 2 suit plus added weapons) ought to have been heavier than the version that crashed through Tony's garage roof/helipad/patio.

Don't recall any of the other heroes being heavy enough to crash through a concrete surface that can support a Rolls or a helicopter...

Comment: To be fair some of the heroes routinely crash through buildings

Comment: Sure, when thrown with super-strength.  How many do it just by dropping a foot or two (after cutting their thrusters or otherwise)?  Crashing through a building when thrown is a measure of toughness, more than of mass.

Comment: The Iron Man Mk.2 had a bunch of guns attached to it to become the War Machine Mk.1. Therefore Rhodes would've been heavier.

Comment: Yep, you're correct, @OrangeDog.  I'll edit to recognize that.

Comment: @ZeissIkon That's true

Comment: Crashing through a building is a measure of pressure, not mass. Hulk could be heavier, but wouldn't do the same because his feet are bigger.

Comment: @OrangeDog We're already talking about a suit that ought to weigh less than half a ton (it'd be less than a ton if it were *solid* steel, without space inside for the man) crashing though a roof that's designed to support a heavy vehicle -- and the other answer gets into density variation and Pym particles.  Physics is out the window in the MCU, isn't it?

Comment: That's my point about pressure. The roof can support a car because cars are broad. It cannot support Iron Man because the feet are small. You stick a spike at the bottom of a helicopter and try to land it then it will crash through too.

Comment: @ZeissIkon You did notice magic and gods and stuff, right? It runs solidly on narrativium, not physics...

Comment: Until Doctor Strange, MCU wasn't admitting magic existed -- not really sure they have yet, since one of his big tricks apparently depended on the Time Stone.  They were careful to make Thor and his people aliens rather than gods, and even Wanda Maximoff was a mutant with psychic powers rather than a true witch.  Still, don't depend on the physics...

Comment: The Mk. 38 (Igor) or Mk.44 (Hulkbuster) suits would be the heaviest ones we've seen on-screen. Either one would be far heavier than the Mk.2 or War Machine armors (which were, technically, the same suit).

Answer (score -2):

I'm just going to throw a few more in here.

First, these two guys don't include armour or growing. These two just go around town weighing this much.

- The Blob (976#)
- Juggernaut (900#)

And the one (or rather the ones) that may weigh the most:

- Celestials (520,000#)

Source: MarvelDirectory.com & Wikipedia.com

Comment: OP is asking about the MCU.

Comment: Oops... my bad. I guess that disqualifies all three then?

Comment: We see a Celestial in GOTG but you'd be hard pressed to describe it as a superhero

Comment: Juggernaut is sort of MCU now (Deadpool 2), but wasn't a hero in any sense...

Answer (score -3):

Pretty sure it's Galactus. Anything that consumes planets and is described as "the physical, metamorphosed embodiment of a cosmos" is going to be very massive.

Comment: Galactus isn't in the MCU as yet.

Comment: Galactus also doesn't count as a super*hero*, as far as I'm aware.